# What is Opengl ES ? What is gl and GLES20 mean?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I am new in opengl. I saw tutorial some have gl at the beginning and some have GLES20 at the beginner and some has GL10.

What are the differences? Is GLES20 mean opengl es2 whereas GL10 mean version 1

Answer (score 2):

GLES20 = OpenGL ES 2.0

GL10 = OpenGL 1.0

In addition there is GLSL (OpenGL Shading Language) which also has its own version number (you can see them at wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language)

GLES is meant for embedded systems. Read more at http://www.khronos.org/